# How to change color to black with \citep

Tags: biblatex, color, citing, natbib

> Edited Version

I am working on the template (MastersDoctoralThesis) downloaded from [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

I searched a lot here for a solution to my problem but couldn't find, please be patient with me.

```
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citep}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

When I use `\citep` to show two authors name and year, I got what I want but in pink color.

I would like to change this color to black with keeping the same format e.g:

> (Autor1 and Autho2, 2019)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The colour probably is coming from `hyperref`. Try using `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` after loading `hyperref`.

Comment: Then please, make a short compilable code (a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) that reproduces this issue so that we can find out where does the colour com from.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik +1,Thanks a lot, I used your helpful comment to search and edit my cls file and I change the cite color from magenta to black

Comment: The problem is that that template loads `hyperref` at the `\begin{document}`, so whatever changes you do before that can be overwritten. If you do `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` after the `\begin{document}` it will work (it will hide all links; if you want just citations, then `\hypersetup{citecolor=black}`).

Comment: If it is not too late you may want to consider dropping the template you are using and starting from a more minimal setup instead. That way you know what each bit of code you add to your document does and don't start with a hugely complicated code base. See also https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md (You can also find many questions about your particular template on this site)

Comment: @moewe actually, it's a bit late. but thanks anyway. Maybe if I got the time, I am going to change.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I wouldn't say it is a problem considering that the preamble shows how to change hyperref settings. And there is a `nohyperref` option to avoid all the clutter from the very start.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following setting

```
 \hypersetup{citecolor=black}
```

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citep}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}} 

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{citecolor=black}  

\begin{document}

\citep{knuth}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Moh Post a compilable code - works in my example

Comment: +1 thanks a lot, I used your answer to search and edit my cls file and I change the cite color from magneta to black.

Comment: @Moh Do not change the class file. See the license. You can make any changes in the preamble, respectively right after `\begin{document}`. Or look at the `\AtBeginDocument{` in the template, where `hyperref` changes are set up. Or don't load `hyperref` at all by uncommenting the `nohyperref` option.